# How to add 3rd party libraries into Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I'm using Eclipse RCP to write a GUI which would use Spring framework related projects, such as:

- Spring WebSocket client
- Spring Web Client

So my question is how to add this dependencies **elegantly**? (Spring does not support osgi for a long time, there are many other ways which are very complicated and tedious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a good **Solution** to solve this problem. It will use following skills: **Maven**, **Eclipse Plugin**

The steps are:

- first, write the **pom.xml** which contains the dependencies you want, for example: spring-websocket

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```
- then, you need to download all websocket jars, you need to use **maven command** to help you to do that :), the jars are all in **/target** folder by default

  `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`

  > Note: maven will handle the dependency tree.
- next, in Eclipse create a **"Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives"** project and **import** these jars

  > Note: Un-check the "Upzip the JAR archives into the project". (Or all jars will be decompressed into folder and files then stored in the project)
- finally, add this plugin project in your main RCP project as a **dependency**. And you can write/run your websocket client now!

Hope this is an elegant way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to convert maven artifacts to OSGi bundles:

1. [Eclipse Bundle Recipes](https://github.com/eclipse/ebr)
2. [p2-maven-plugin](http://projects.reficio.org/p2-maven-plugin) in combination with a Tycho and a Nexus repository you have a elegant tooling to add thirdparty dependencies to your Eclipse-RCP project.

Comment: take a look at For a more detail description take a look at [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#automatic-conversion-of-jars-to-osgi-bundles).